# Error: Unable to resolve module `./node_modules\expo\AppEntry` from ``

Tags: javascript, react-native, yarnpkg, expo

I can't figure out what is happening here, I'm getting the following error when trying to open my project in the Expo Client App:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./node_modules\expo\AppEntry` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\expo\AppEntry(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * node_modules\expo\AppEntry\index(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

> `node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js` exists.

I've others expo projects working fine with SDK 39, 38. I tried downgrading the expo-cli and upgrading the SDK to 39 but no luck, the only solution was initialize another project and move all my code to that project, also downgrade the SDK to 36 for compatibility with the code, for a little time the project worked, after restarting the PC, and re running the project, the error came back

#### Enviroment

```
Environment
Expo CLI 3.28.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
Binaries:
Node: 12.18.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.19.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
npm: 6.14.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: 20200424.164118.0 - D:\Instaladores\watchman\windows\bin\watchman.EXE
SDKs:
Android SDK:
API Levels: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 7, 8, 9
Build Tools: 24.0.3, 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.2, 27.0.1, 27.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
System Images: android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
Android NDK: 16.1.4479499
npmPackages:
expo: ^36.0.0 => 36.0.2
react: ^16.12.0 => 16.12.0
react-dom: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
react-native-web: ^0.11.7 => 0.11.7
react-navigation: 4.1.1 => 4.1.1
Expo Workflow: managed
```

#### Yarn Global Packages

```
info "@capacitor/cli@1.3.0" has binaries:
   - capacitor
   - cap
info "@ionic/cli@6.7.0" has binaries:
   - ionic
info "@ionic/lab@2.0.18" has binaries:
   - ionic-lab
info "capacitor-resources@2.0.0" has binaries:
   - capacitor-resources
info "cordova@9.0.0" has binaries:
   - cordova
info "electron@8.0.2" has binaries:
   - electron
info "eslint@6.8.0" has binaries:
   - eslint
info "expo@36.0.0" has binaries:
   - expo
info "firebase-tools@7.9.0" has binaries:
   - firebase
info "generact@0.4.0" has binaries:
   - generact
info "ionic@5.4.12" has binaries:
   - ionic
info "jest@24.9.0" has binaries:
   - jest
info "mocha@6.2.2" has binaries:
   - mocha
   - _mocha
info "native-run@0.3.0" has binaries:
   - native-run
info "nodemon@2.0.2" has binaries:
   - nodemon
info "pm2@4.2.1" has binaries:
   - pm2
   - pm2-dev
   - pm2-docker
   - pm2-runtime
info "serve@11.2.0" has binaries:
   - serve
info "ts-jest@24.2.0" has binaries:
   - ts-jest
```

I've posted a issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11074

Also published a repository that is giving me that error: https://github.com/Alain00/expo-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I included node_modules in watchman ignore_dirs... watchman is used for crawling and watching the fs. You won't be able to resolve any node_modules if you do this.